# SQL: Need to remove duplicate rows in query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need help in getting this result either by using SQL query or procedure. My sample table structure is given below.

Required Result :

```
docid    status
24       Waiver Requested
26       Waiver Requested
27       Rejected
```

Table A:

```
docid
----------
24
26
27
```

Table b:

```
docid     Status
24     Waiver Requested
26     Rejected
26     Waiver Requested
27     Rejected
27     Rejected
```

Comment: Why do your desired results have `26,Waiver Requested` rather than `26, Rejected`? What criteria are you using here? Also what is the PK on TableB?

Comment: **HOW** do you know which of the rows from TableB to select?? Is there some additional column in TableB to sort by??

Comment: Your question contains too less context. Please describe the business rules for erasing duplicates.

Comment: You show that in table b you have 2 values for docid 26, Rejected and Waiver Requested.  What criterea do you use to select one over the other?

Comment: if status is having two different values like Waiver Requested and Rejected for a doc id , i need only Waiver Requested status alone.

Comment: I see you've just tagged your question as _Oracle_. Well, my solutions is for MySql only. Next time tag your question as needed please.

Comment: Is this homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123782/joining-data-from-5-tables-without-duplicate-values-and-getting-result-with-cust

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing all of your business rules other than the one you gave, here is a more general solution.

Create another table (or perhaps your data model already has one) with the possible statuses in them:

```
CREATE TABLE status_rank (
   status   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
   rank     NUMBER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (status_name)
);
```

This table is used to rank the statuses in order of precedence. In other words, if "Waiver Requested" should be selected over "Rejected" in the case of duplicates, then use a precedence of 1 for waivers and 2 for rejects.

So now the query can make use of this additional ranking table:

```
SELECT b.docid, r.status
  FROM b,
       status_rank r,
       (SELECT b.id, min(r.rank)
          FROM b, status_rank r
         WHERE b.status = r.status
         GROUP BY id) s
 WHERE b.docid = s.docid
   AND r.rank = s.rank
   AND b.status = r.status;
```

There are numerous ways to actually do the query, but this should show you the general idea.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very good MSDN article "Find and/or Delete Duplicate Rows"
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=DuplicateRows
Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Not the same thing. The OP is looking to apply business rules to the detection, and the "duplicates" aren't really duplicates. The link you posted is for detecting true duplicates where all the data is the same. If the OP just needed to perform a query without duplicate results SELECT DISTINCT would serve the purpose.